# auto update war file with new one by downloading from other server

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

**We are building this Java EE web application and deploying on tomcat 7.0 on every clients pc. as this application has to run offline.
Every day we have new deployments and bug fixes producing new war file. I want some method so that those old deployments would come to know about new version of war and download it from a sever and deploy it on tomcat. I have searched a lot but could not find anything ,read about cron jobs or ant scripts ...please throw some light on it. tomcat 7.0 is what we are using **

Comment: Do you really need to install it on every PC? if you need to have separate instance for every user you can use clustering. Clustering supports automatic deployment of new changes to all instances.

Comment: our application runs on clients pc on tomcat server where there is no internet..that is how it works so instances is not the worry.i want to update all clients with new war...by not going to each client but there should be something on server that it looks for new war file evryday..to downlad from a website and deploy it automatically

Comment: In that case, its a matter of pushing a file from server to client in a scheduled manner. You may find different solution for file transfer.

Comment: i do not track the clients with any address ...my application is not running over internet......it is running as localhost...

Comment: my clients are not tracked by ip or anything.  they have the application running as localhost....i want the application or the server on the client to check for new version when they connect to internet...if there is a new version is should download it and deplaoy it replacing the current web app

Answer (score 0):

You need to write separate scheduled task for that. You may write a task using `TimerTask` which will poll on your server folder for the new war, if new war is  available then task will bring down tomcat, deploy new war and start tomcat. You may use Apache common's `FileAlterationObserver` to observe the changes in folder to check for new war.